# Ruby (without rails) using activerecord, insert into does not work

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I need to insert a new record into an existing table in a databse. I tried both approaches below:

```
  class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.add_new_user
   new_user = UserDetail.new
   new_user.first_name = 'Joe'
   new_user.last_name = 'Smith'
   new_user.user_id = 'TEST'
   new_user.save
 end

 def self.add_new_user_2

UserDetail.create(user_id: 'TEST', first_name: 'Joe', 
                  last_name: 'Smith')
 end
```

However, both approaches give me the error below:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00926: 
    missing VALUES keyword: INSERT INTO "USER_DETAIL" DEFAULT VALUES
```

What am I missing? Please share your solutions.

(Using Ruby 1.9.3, ActiveRecord 4.2.4)

Comment: What Oracle adapter are you using?

Comment: I am using: gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.6.7'

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord makes assumptions about primary keys.  It is expecting to find a primary key on your UserDetail table called "ID". Should look something like.

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = :user_detail
    self.primary_key = :user_id

    def self.add_new_user
       new_user = UserDetail.new
       new_user.first_name = 'Joe'
       new_user.last_name = 'Smith'
       new_user.user_id = 1
       new_user.save
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, the USER_DETAIL table does not have a primary key,  what it has is a constraint  called  **USER_EXPIRE_DT_UK **(USER_ID and EXPIRE_DT two columns in the USER_DETAIL table). How do I define this in ActiveRecord model class?

Comment: @user3314970 Changing the ID column is detailed in the AR docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions